# Bootstrap scrollable panel

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make my content inside my panel scrollable

```
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body scrollable-panel">
            SCROLLABLE CONTENT HERE
          </div>
        </div>
```

I've tried adding

```
.scrollable-panel{
      height:300px;
      overflow-y:scroll;
      width:100%;
      }
```

But nothing I do seems to work.
Can anyone help ?

Comment: You code is working fine, you just have one line of text, add more text and scroll bar will appear. here is working demo https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/85hqfaq9/

Answer (score -1):

```
.scrollable0panel{
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```